# HTML5 Pattern for allowing only 5 comma separated words without including a space

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I basically don't know how to make HTML5 Patterns so that's why I am asking this question. I just want to create a pattern that would be applied onto a `input[type=text]` thorough `pattern` attribute newly introduced by the HTML5 but I have no idea on how to implement that pattern.

The pattern includes the following things:

1. Allow only 5 comma separated words
2. No space could be added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^(\w+,){4}\w+$` is the pattern you need: repeat "any number of word characters followed by comma" four times, then "just word characters". If you want "up to five", the solution would be

```
^(\w+,){0,4}\w+$
```

Detailed explanation (adapted from http://www.regex101.com):

```
^      assert position at start of the string (i.e. start matching from start of string)

1st    Capturing group (\w+,){0,4}
   Quantifier {0,4}: Between 0 and 4 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

\w+    match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
   Quantifier +: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

,      matches the character , literally

\w+    match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
   Quantifier +: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

$ assert position at end of the string
```

If you don't want numbers as part of the match, replace every instance of `\w` in the above with `[a-zA-Z]` - it will match only lowercase and uppercase letters A through Z.

**UPDATE** In response to your comment, if you want no group of characters to be more than 10 long, you can modify the above expression to

```
^(\w{1,10},){0,4}\w{1,10}$
```

Now the "quantifier" is `{1,10}` instead of `+` : that means "between 1 and 10 times" instead of "1 or more times".

Comment: Can you explain me what does that pattern mean exactly, please?

Comment: I just want a little tweak more that there should be only 10 characters allowed for a word before the comma. Please help me again. :) I would be thankful to you.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui I have updated my answer to address your new condition.